# Hide Page Title and Command bar from Modern UI SharePoint pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, modern-experience

Can we hide below from modern UI pages using css?

[image: odern]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you need to use the custom css on the Modern page (Not good practice though).

Try using below CSS:

```
<style>
    div.commandBarWrapper {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

To add this code you will need a script editor web part. Below is the Modern Script Editor web-part created using SPFx:

[Modern Script Editor web-part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor).

Comment: Try this and let me know if this works for you. I can provide you the SPFx package(.sppkg) file of modern script editor if you need.

Comment: Thank let me check if required i will ask for spfx package

Comment: it worked for me i set it global thank you

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the page title and command bar for all the modern page, we can create an application customizer to inject the CSS style below to achieve it.

```
div[class^='pageTitle_']{
    display: none !important;
}
div.commandBarWrapper {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Source code: [SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)