# Is it possible to customize the HTML from a Sharepoint Modern Experience page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, administration, html

I know that you can customize the HTML/CSS of a Sharepoint Classic page.

But is it also possible to do this with Sharepoint Modern Experience page?

If so how?

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer given below? Does this answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using SharePoint out of the box web parts.

However, you can do DOM manipulations using SharePoint framework (SPFx).

**1. For single modern page**:

If you want to customize particular modern page, you can use modern script editor web part.

**Example**:

You can use custom CSS like below on the Modern page to hide page title and command bar.

Try using below CSS:

```
<style>
    div.commandBarWrapper {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

To add this code you will need a script editor web part. Below is the Modern Script Editor web-part created using SPFx:

[Modern Script Editor web-part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor).

**Source**: [Hide Page Title and Command bar from Modern UI SharePoint pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269748/hide-page-title-and-command-bar-from-modern-ui-sharepoint-pages/269752#269752)

**2. For all modern pages**:

If you want to customize all modern pages in site, you can create an SPFx application customizer to inject the custom CSS/JS to achieve it.

**References**:

1. [SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)
2. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: DOM manipulation in this way isn't supported, which is worse than being not recommended