# How to remove border from file and media web part?

Tags: web-part, file, embedded

I would like to embed a **markdown** file in a sharepoint online modern page, using the [file and media web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-and-media-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c) or some alternative:

[image]

**How can I remove the border that is shown around the file content?**

Is there a custom pnp file web part, I could inherit from? I only could find one for viewing a whole document library:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-documents-detailslist

Unfortunately, the source code for the original file and media web part does not seem to be available: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-solutions/issues/312

Comment: I don't think it is possible using the SharePoint out of the box web part functionality.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a css style or something for the website template or maybe an extra web part to include markdown or word components?

Comment: You can apply custom CSS using the modern script editor (SPFx) web part or SPFx application customizer. Check this thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306103/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-html-from-a-sharepoint-modern-experience-page/306106#306106

Answer (score 0):

There are PnP Modern Search web parts available that you can use (https://pnp.github.io/blog/post/using-the-pnp-modern-search-web-parts/). You can use the @pnp/sp library when building your SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web parts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts).