# How to link another markdown file in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: hyperlink

I have a markdown file `foo.md` in my Documents folder and would like to link it to a file `baa.md` in the same folder.

I tried following syntax in foo.md:

```
# Foo

[baa]

[baa]: ./baa.md
```

- If I open foo.md in the HTML Viewer and click on the link, nothing happens.
- If I right click and select the option "Open link in new tab", the file is downloaded instead of navigating to the file in Sharepoint.
- If I use the file and media webpart to show the markdown file inside a Page... and click on the link, I get an empty page.

**=> How to correctly link another markdown file in Sharepoint, so that I can easily follow the link?**

I also tried following variants without luck:

- `[baa]`  (without defining the link at the end of the page)
- `[[baa]]`
- `[baa](../baa.md)`

As a workaround, I also tried to move `baa.md` to the "hidden folder" `Documents/Forms` ... where links seem to point by default. However, that does not seem to be allowed.

**Related:**

- https://marked.js.org/demo/
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/wiki-in-modern-page-format/m-p/673543/highlight/true#M30788
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77713086/how-to-write-sharepoint-online-extension-to-store-meta-data-in-markdown-files
- [How to remove border from file and media web part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310586/how-to-remove-border-from-file-and-media-web-part)

Comment: Could someone please create a new tag "markdown" here on sharepoint.stackexchange.com? I don't have enough reputation, yet.